# powerapps Radio button control

Tags: radio-button, controls, items, powerapps

I have a gallery and a radio button. 
In the gallery where the user has to answer questions.

Each question can be a radio button with multiple choice answers, for example  one could be a yes no response another could be a yes no unknown choice.

These choices are determined from the list field called answerchoice .

In the answerchoice field it might be populated with

```
yes\no or yes\no\unknown or 1\2\3\4.
```

Therefore in the items of the radio button I need to pass the values of the answerchoice field

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share what did you do till now. Some screenshots of your Gallery and buttons should be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the separator for the options is the `\` character, then you can use the [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-split) to convert that into a collection that you can set to the Items property of the radio button control:

```
Split(ThisItem.Value, "\")
```